# android: how to control starting/finishing an app from command line

Tags: android, android-activity, command

I know we can use
adb shell am start -n [package]/[activity] to start an launcher activity.
But does anyone know how to close it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have an activity that calls `finish()` when it receives a particular action. Then send this action using the `am` command.